# LoadRunner - Manual Correlation - Unable to get the value using web_reg_save_param

Tags: performance, performance-testing, correlation, loadrunner

I am using LoadRunner to test the performance of an application which is a Siebel CRM based application. The issue I am facing is I am not able to get the SRN number which is unique for each of the session.

The code I am using to capture SRN is below

```
//HELLO YOUR CODE STARTS HERE.....FOR MANUAL CORRELATION
web_reg_save_param("Siebel_SRN",    
    "NOTFOUND=ERROR",                      
    "LB=SRN`",
    "RB=`", 
    "Ord=All", 
    "Search=All",   
    "IgnoreRedirections=Yes",
    "RelFrameId=All",       
    LAST);
lr_output_message( "Siebel_SRN value is %s", lr_eval_string( "{Siebel_SRN}" ) );
//HELLO YOUR CODE ENDS HERE.....FOR MANUAL CORRELATION
```

If I search by SRN` I am able to see the SRN value.

Below is the response I am getting from the server. I am setting the boundary correctly ( I believe so ) but not able to get the SRN value.

```
vuser_init.c(161):     7/23048/scripts/HICalendarUI.htm`sui`false`vfn`_sweclient._swecontent._sweview`IsWebSocket
vuser_init.c(161):     BSReady`false`WebSocketServerPort``SweBusyTimer`30`lt`1471312453347`MR1`Y`cqt`-1`ui`L17LOA
vuser_init.c(161):     D`IsAutoOn`false`ect`Link`SRN`ABrcHGKVMlEGktXB3ekmRUEOy6rYzkMmy7OicIW0yHMb`ec`<span class=
vuser_init.c(161):     \\"siebui-icon-icon_select\\"><img src=\\"images/icon_select.gif\\" border=\\"0\\" align=\\
vuser_init.c(161):     "absmiddle\\" alt=\\"Pick Applet\\"  title=\\"Pick Applet\\" >\\<\\/span>`cks`1-14TA9_DHHS
vuser_init.c(161):     +L17_43%7c1470288710%7c1471223560_0_23048__L`vs`15.9.0.0 SIA [23048]  ENU`USC`1`IsMsgBarEna
vuser_init.c(161):     bled`true`lodc`0`IsMobileApplication`false`iri`<span class=\\"siebui-icon-icon_required\\"
vuser_init.c(161):     ><img src=\\"images/icon_req.gif\\" border=\\"0\\" space=\\"0\\" hspace=\\"0\\" alt=\\"Req
```

I am getting the below message while replaying

```
 No match found for the requested parameter "Siebel_SRN". Either the specified boundaries
 were not found in the response or the matched text is longer than current max html parameter size of 999999 bytes.
 The total length of the response is 15062 bytes. You can use 
"web_set_max_html_param_len" to increase the max parameter size.    [MsgId: MERR-26377] [Time:2016-08-16 11:54:27]
```

and the output for Siebel_SRN is

```
user_init.c(296): Registering web_reg_save_param was successful     [MsgId: MMSG-26390]
vuser_init.c(307): Warning: The string 'Siebel_SRN' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
vuser_init.c(307): Siebel_SRN value is {Siebel_SRN} [Time:2016-08-16 11:54:21]
```

I am doing something silly. But not able to figure it out.Please help me in resolving this issue. Advance Thanks

Comment: Has your management sent you to training on this tool or provided you with a mentor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you placed the `web_reg_save_param` before the target request step (`web_url`, `web_custom_request`, `web_submit_form` etc.) as correlations should always be registered beforehand.

Also you should not pass `Ord=All` argument: it creates an array on parameters like `Siebel_SRN_1`, `Siebel_SRN_2` and so on. In your case, there is only one instance of the SRN value in the response. `IgnoreRedirections=Yes` looks odd as well: ignoring HTTP redirections is not needed in general case. Check [the official documentation](http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/function_reference/Content/web/lrFr_web_reg_save_param.htm) for more information.